# How do you pull find the min value of a specific column, when left joined to another table, in Google BigQuery SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm struggling to pull back min and max values on a transaction level basis. What I am trying to do is pair one type of transaction to another through left join. However, since there's multiple transactions that could be matched to my exception population, I'm pulling many duplicates. I've tried to followed the existing question and implement those tips but still not successful.

Here's an example of my query:

```
SELECT *

FROM ( Select DISTINCT 
        B.POS_TRANS_ID,
        B.SLS_DT,
        (MAX(B.SLS_DT) < H.BUS_DT) AS MAX_SLS_DT,
        (MIN(DATE_DIFF(H.BUS_DT,B.SLS_DT,DAY))) AS MIN_DAY_DIFF, 
        B.NET_EXT_RETL_AMT,
        H.STR_NBR,
        H.MKUP_MKDN_CTRL_NBR,
        H.MKDN_RSN_TXT,
        H.BUS_DT,
        H.CURR_RETL_AMT,
        H.TRANS_ID

FROM `EXAMPLE_TABLE` H
      left join `miami` B
      on H.SKU_NBR = B.SKU_NBR
      and H.STR_NBR = B.STR_NBR
      and (H.UNT_CNT*-1) = B.QTY_SOLD
      and (H.NET_MUMD_AMT*-1) = (B.CURR_RETL_AMT)

where 
      B.QTY_SOLD < 0
      and cast(MKUP_MKDN_CTRL_NBR as string) not like ('99%')
      AND H.TRANS_ID IN ('FLORIDA_TRANS')


GROUP BY 
        B.POS_TRANS_ID,
        B.SLS_DT, 
        B.NET_EXT_RETL_AMT,
        H.STR_NBR,
        H.MKUP_MKDN_CTRL_NBR,
        H.MKDN_RSN_TXT,
        H.BUS_DT,
        H.CURR_RETL_AMT,
        H.TRANS_ID)Z

WHERE MAX_SLS_DT IS TRUE
      AND Z.MKUP_MKDN_CTRL_NBR = 69308
      AND Z.STR_NBR = '3204'
```

Here's an example of my results:

```
 POS_TRANS_ID   SLS_DT    MAX_SLS_DT    MIN_DAY_DIFF    NET_EXT_RETL_AMT    STR_NBR MKUP_MKDN_CTRL_NBR
        4768    10/4/2017   TRUE            566                 -99           3204       69308
        5441    1/3/2017    TRUE            840                 -99           3204       69308
        8824    4/25/2018   TRUE            363                 -99           3204       69308
        8870    3/10/2018   TRUE            409                 -99           3204       69308
```

when I actually ONLY would like to the min date-diff and max_sls_dt by transaction by store...

Desired results:

```
 POS_TRANS_ID   SLS_DT    MAX_SLS_DT    MIN_DAY_DIFF    NET_EXT_RETL_AMT    STR_NBR MKUP_MKDN_CTRL_NBR
        8824    4/25/2018   TRUE            363                 -99           3204       69308
```

I'm very much still learning SQL so any help would SO appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`ROW_NUMBER` is one option here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        B.POS_TRANS_ID,
        B.SLS_DT,
        MAX(B.SLS_DT) < H.BUS_DT AS MAX_SLS_DT,
        MIN(DATE_DIFF(H.BUS_DT, B.SLS_DT, DAY)) AS MIN_DAY_DIFF, 
        B.NET_EXT_RETL_AMT,
        H.STR_NBR,
        H.MKUP_MKDN_CTRL_NBR,
        H.MKDN_RSN_TXT,
        H.BUS_DT,
        H.CURR_RETL_AMT,
        H.TRANS_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY H.STR_NBR
                           ORDER BY MIN(DATE_DIFF(H.BUS_DT, B.SLS_DT, DAY))) rn
    FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE H
    LEFT JOIN miami B
        ON H.SKU_NBR = B.SKU_NBR AND
           H.STR_NBR = B.STR_NBR AND
           H.UNT_CNT*-1 = B.QTY_SOLD AND
           H.NET_MUMD_AMT*-1 = B.CURR_RETL_AMT AND
           MKUP_MKDN_CTRL_NBR = 69308
    WHERE
        B.QTY_SOLD < 0 AND
        CAST(MKUP_MKDN_CTRL_NBR AS string) NOT LIKE '99%' AND
        H.TRANS_ID = 'FLORIDA_TRANS'
    GROUP BY 
        B.POS_TRANS_ID,
        B.SLS_DT, 
        B.NET_EXT_RETL_AMT,
        H.STR_NBR,
        H.MKUP_MKDN_CTRL_NBR,
        H.MKDN_RSN_TXT,
        H.BUS_DT,
        H.CURR_RETL_AMT,
        H.TRANS_ID
    HAVING
        MAX(B.SLS_DT) < H.BUS_DT IS TRUE
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to pull this view across very stores/skus. So I can't limit the query since I'm looking for about 350K records. That's the size of my exception population and I'm trying to match a transaction to each record.

Comment: Is `STR_NBR` the column which keeps track of the store?  If not, which column does that?

Comment: Yes, STR_NBR is the store indentifer. All of this data is on a sku/store/transaction level.

Comment: @Tam I have updated my answer with an option using `ROW_NUMBER` which might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I had to slightly modify it since GBQ doesn't allow having an aggregate function in the where statement. I filter on the MAX_SLS_DT IS TRUE outside of the CTE statement but it's not returning any results. I'm unsure why however.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and that condition should be in the `HAVING` clause, reload the page to see the correction.

Comment: It's still coming back with no results but I think I just realized why. MKUP_MKDN_CTRL_NBR doesn't exists in the Miami table but when even when I tried to remove that from the left join it still doesn't work.

Comment: Without seeing/knowing your data, this is as much help as I can give.  Mabye you can fix my query yourself and edit the answer.

Comment: No worries. Truly, I really appreciate you trying! Thank you. I didn't know about the row partition option before so I'm going to try to continue to tweak the query to see if I can produce the desired result from there. Have a great night.

Comment: The basic idea is to just retain rows where the row number is 1.  That should occur when the date diff is smallest, and one for each store.  My guess that your current query/data has some issue, which needs to be resolved.